# SENCHA TOUCH Ext.form.Select. How populate a combo with data coming from a hardcoded variable?

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs

Saluts!!!!
I have my combo, IN SENCHA TOUCH, declared as the following

```
Ext.regModel('modelo', {fields: ['id', 'nombre']});

aaStore = new Ext.data.Store({
    model: 'modelo',
    autoLoad: (noLoad !== true),
    autoDestroy : true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
    url: url,
    extraParams: extraParams,
    reader: {
        type: 'array'
        }
    }
});
 bSelect = new Ext.form.Select({Ext.apply({
        label: label,
        name: name,
        store: aaStore,
        placeHolder: config.placeHolder || 'Seleccione...',
        valueField: config.valueField || 'id',
        displayField: config.displayField || 'nombre',
        useClearIcon: config.useClearIcon || true
    })

})
```

I am almost new to Sencha touch, and I need to populate my combo "Ext.form.Select" from data coming from a variable, 
I mean, I found a plain of examples loading data from a proxy, dynamically, but that's not what I need. I need to load data to my combo from a variable that is hardcoded. I mean I've built the variable, an array type variable, like this:

var **varArray** = [['1','2'],['3','4'],['5','6']]

and I want to charge that data to my combo **bSelect** ,

I've tried the following:

this.bSelect.store.loadData(**varArray**,false);

but, although the data has been charged, I cannot be displayed, and when I select and element of that combo, it appears like "undefined"

Please, somebody help me out. How can I load data from an array variable into my sencha touch combo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Ext.regModel('modelo', {
    fields: [
        { name : 'id', type : 'string'},
        {name : 'nombre', type : 'string'}
    ]
});

aaStore = new Ext.data.Store({
    model: 'modelo',
    data : [{id : '1', nombre : '2'},{id : '3', nombre : '4'}, {id : '5', nombre : '6'}]
});

bSelect = new Ext.form.Select({
        label: label,
        name: name,
        store: aaStore,
        placeHolder: config.placeHolder || 'Seleccione...',
        valueField: config.valueField || 'id',
        displayField: config.displayField || 'nombre',
        useClearIcon: config.useClearIcon || true
    });

console.log(bSelect);
```

i think this should work for you

Answer (score 1):

You can add an options array to your config object.  [From the docs:](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/1-1/#!/api/Ext.form.Select-cfg-options)

> options : Array (Optional) An array of select options.

```
[
    {text: 'First Option',  value: 'first'},
    {text: 'Second Option', value: 'second'},
    {text: 'Third Option',  value: 'third'}
]
```

> Note: option object member names should correspond with defined
>   valueField and displayField values. This config will be ignore if a
>   store instance is provided